# Will I lose the AMT tax I paid if my startup fails?

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options, tax-credit, alternative-minimum-tax

I recently parted ways with a startup.  I was granted options and now must exercise them.  When I exercise them, I will incur the Alternative Minimum Tax (AMT).

If the company fails and goes bankrupt, am I able to retrieve the AMT I paid or is it lost?  Am I able to use the AMT as a tax credit for the following tax year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tax, not a deposit. So no, you will not get it back.

You will be able to use your AMT credit, under certain conditions, see the [instructions to form 8801](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-8801,-Credit-for-Prior-Year-Minimum-Tax%E2%80%94Individuals,-Estates,-and-Trusts). Obviously, the actual value of the credit depends on your other items of income, and you may end up never using the whole credit.